# Saving detached entity navigation property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

**Is it possible to save/update navigation property of a detached entity in Entity Framework 5 Code First and if yes, how?**

I have tried (both with and without fluent mapping) but it does not update the foreign key. Initial value is null and when I set it and then call

`dbContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges();`

the foreign key remains null.

Answer (score 0):

Detached entities are not being tracked by context and therefore any changes to these entities are not affected entities tracked by the context. What you can try however is to attach the entity the navigation property on the detached entity is pointing to and then manipulate it.

Comment: I have tried that but it did not work. I guess I will switch to the attached entities approach...